# How can I left join multiple data from the same mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

This is my table `position`:

```
+----+---------+------+--------+---------+
| id | teacher | cook | doctor | dentist |
+----+---------+------+--------+---------+
|  1 |       3 |    4 |      2 |       1 |
+----+---------+------+--------+---------+
```

And this is my table `people`:

```
+----+-----------+--------+-----+
| id | firstname |  name  | age |
+----+-----------+--------+-----+
|  1 | Fred      | Miller |  42 |
|  2 | Emily     | Rose   |  32 |
|  3 | Ben       | Harper |  38 |
|  4 | Samanta   | Jones  |  35 |
+----+-----------+--------+-----+
```

My request from the mySQL database

```
$pdo = $db->query('
SELECT *, position.id AS id, people.id AS people_id 
FROM position 
LEFT JOIN people 
ON position.teacher=people.id;
ON position.cook=people.id;
ON position.doctor=people.id;
ON position.dentist=people.id;
');

while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "The teacher is "$row['firstname']." ".$row['name'];
echo "The cook is "$row['firstname']." ".$row['name'];
echo "The doctor is "$row['firstname']." ".$row['name'];
echo "The dentist is "$row['firstname']." ".$row['name'];
}
```

My result is:

```
The teacher is Ben Harper
The cook is Ben Harper
The doctor is Ben Harper
The dentist is Ben Harper
```

The result I need:

```
The teacher is Ben Harper
The cook is Samanta Jones
The doctor is Emiliy Rose
The dentist is Fred Miller
```

Comment: what about changing table structures: 1- change position table to (`id`, `positionName`) 2- add extra column to people table `position_id` .. then you have simpler query

Comment: Yes, could be an idea!

Comment: @Jarla It's the only idea.

Comment: @Strawberry rahul_m gave a second idea

Comment: Yeah, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @mohsenkw I didn't get exactly how you want to change the position table.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh ok, didn't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be better if you restructure your table.

```
+----+------------+
| id | position   |       
+----+------------|
|  1 |  teacher   |
|  2 |  cook      |
|  3 |  doctor    |
|  4 |  dentist   |
+----+------------+


+----+-----------+--------+-----+-------------+
| id | firstname |  name  | age | position_id |
+----+-----------+--------+-----+-------------+
|  1 | Fred      | Miller |  42 |  4          |
|  2 | Emily     | Rose   |  32 |  3          |
|  3 | Ben       | Harper |  38 |  1          |
|  4 | Samanta   | Jones  |  35 |  2          |
+----+-----------+--------+-----+-------------+
```

Here you can have a foreign key reference on people.position_id and position.id.
This way you can have many people with same position.

```
SELECT position.id id
     , people.id people_id
     , people.firstname
     , people.name
  FROM position 
  LEFT 
  JOIN people 
    ON people.position_id = position.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments and answers above, if you *can* restructure your table, you absolutely should -- as others have mentioned, it's better to restructure it to have that extra column, and then your query will be both simpler and much more efficient.  But if you're stuck in a position where you can't (and if you only have a SMALL amount of data as presented, so that the inefficiency of this isn't too much of a concern), then you could use a UNION to glue several simple queries together :

```
Select position.id, firstname, lastname, 'cook' AS position
FROM position LEFT JOIN people ON position.cook = people.id

UNION

Select position.id, firstname, lastname, 'teacher' AS position
FROM position LEFT JOIN people ON position.teacher = people.id

UNION
...
```

Again, this is NOT an efficient approach -- you should restructure your data if you can.   But if you can't for whatever reason, then this would get you back the data you need in a set of rows that pulls back what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$pdo = $db->query('
SELECT *, position.id AS id, people.id AS people_id,
(case when position.teacher <> '' then 'teacher'
when position.cook <> '' then 'cook'
when position.doctor <> '' then 'doctor' 
when position.dentist <> '' then 'dentist') position_name
FROM position 
LEFT JOIN people 
ON position.teacher=people.id;
ON position.cook=people.id;
ON position.doctor=people.id;
ON position.dentist=people.id;
');

while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "The ".$row['position_name']." is "$row['firstname']." ".$row['name'];
}
```